# Implement a Fingerprint based Authentication System in Web Application

Tags: angularjs, spring, jhipster

I want to develop a Web based Finger Print Authentication system and I have no clue of how to retrieve the fingerprint from the scanner to and bring to my Backend API.

Comment: Have you attempted to research any existing material on how to achieve this? Do you have an initial plan of how it might even be possible to achieve this or are you just hoping someone on stackoverflow will do all of this for you?

Comment: If you use OIDC and Okta, you could use Okta Verify for MFA and it supports Touch ID.